# Unable to view all tracks (uploaded on my SoundCloud account) in my android app

Tags: android, api, soundcloud

I have uploaded 75 tracks on my SoundCloud account. Using the SoundCloud API I'm able to display these tracks in my RecyclerView track list but only a limited number of tracks appear. How should I display all 75 tracks or at least be able to search for the rest?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need  to use `pagination`.

> Most results from our API are returned as a collection. The number of items in the collection returned is `limited to 50 by default` with a maximum value of 200. Most endpoints support a linked_partitioning parameter that will allow you to page through collections. When this parameter is passed, the response will contain a next_href property if there are additional results. To fetch the next page of results, simply follow that URI. If the response does not contain a next_href property, you have reached the end of the results.

[Documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#pagination)

Comment: I think I'll need to use retrofit but since I'm not using it I'll have to change a lot of code. Isn't there any other way? also, I don't know how to implement that in java do you know any references that can help me?